# prometheus в докер контейнере не имеет доступа к локальной машине MacBook m1

Tags: docker, prometheus

Локальная машина это MacBook m1. На localhost развернуто node.js приложение с эндпоинтом localhost:9650/metrics. Локально обращение по этому эндпоинту позволяет получить метрики prometheus.
В докер контейнере развернут прометеус командой

```
docker run -p 9090:9090  -v xxx/prometheus/prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus
```

файл конфигурации prometheus.yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'localhost:9650' ]
```

После запуска вебинтерфейс прометеуса доступен по адресу localhost:9090
Но таргет localhost:9650 из контейнера не доступен.

Что пробовал использовать:

- соединять порт 9650 с портом 9651 в контейнере, указывая этот порт у таргета.
- использовать --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway и указывать тагрет как host.docker.internal:9650
- --net host
- brew install chipmk/tap/docker-mac-net-connect

Comment: Просто используйте host.docker.internal (это адрес по которому хост доступен изнутри контейнера) не добавляя --add-host.

Comment: Во втором пункте указал это решение. К сожалению на m1 сеть не работает из коробки.

Comment: Что-то делаете не так, у меня работает из коробки (без `--add-host`)

Comment: Вспомните пожалуйста как Вы настраивали окружение. У меня это работает только на линукс. Т.к. докер не работает на unix, в качестве прослойки используется виртуальная машина. Возможно Вы что-на настраивали чтобы пробрасывать соединение через нее к локальной машине.

Comment: Кстати, как временное решение просто использую внешний адрес моей локальной машины, в этом случае все работает. Но хотелось бы разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: Никаких настроек не делал ЕМНИП (да и это способ из докуменцаи). Докер десктоп версии 4.14.1, движок 20.10.21. Проверяю так: запускаю в одном терминале `nc -l 10000`, а в другом - `docker run -ti alpine:latest /bin/sh -c "apk add curl; curl http://host.docker.internal:10000"` и вижу, что в неткат запрос приходит. У вас этот самый простой тест тоже не работает?

Comment: Работает, это доказывает наличие доступа к host.docker.internal. Пока нет идей, почему prom/prometheus образ не стучит к host.docker.internal. Спасибо.

Comment: А где в конфигурации вы указали, что он должен ходить на ` host.docker.internal`? В том куске конфига указан localhost, а это адрес самого контейнера prometheus

Comment: Во время тестирования host.docker.internal указывал вместо localhost, но т.к. результата положительного не получил, разместил без host.docker.internal, а в списке ниже указал что пробовал использовать. В данный момент там внешний адрес моей локальной машины.

Comment: А ошибка вообще какая? Текст ошибки добавьте

Comment: Get "http://host.docker.internal:9650/metrics": connection refused

Comment: А если ноду остановить, а вместо нее запустить nc на том же порту?

Comment: Не нашел в мануале как nc принимать соединение на определенный эндпоинт, прометеус стучит на /metrics по умолчанию.

Comment: Для этого теста не нужно на endpoint, запускайте просто "nc -l 9650", он покажет любой запрос на этот порт. Это простой способ отбросить гипотезу, что проблема не в том, как node слушает порт.

Comment: Поймал 
❯ nc -l 10000
GET /metrics HTTP/1.1
Host: host.docker.internal:10000
User-Agent: Prometheus/2.41.0

Comment: Доказывает что сеть есть. Но прометеус с эндпоинтом не соединяется.
Если поставить прометеус на локальную машину и подключить этот же конфиг, но с localhost:xxxx, метрики получает.

Comment: замените localhost на 127.0.0.1 (или 0.0.0.0) при старте ноды. Для localhost nodejs не слушает все интерфейсы

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе для доступа к хосту из докер контейнера на маке достаточно использовать `host.docker.internal`.

Это легко проверить. Достаточно запустить в одном терминале `nc -l 10000`, а в другом - `docker run -ti alpine:latest /bin/sh -c "apk add curl; curl http://host.docker.internal:10000"`. Будет видно, что в неткат запрос приходит.

У вас же проблема в том, что если в nodejs использовать `localhost` в качестве имени хоста, то при этом приложение не слушает все сетевые интерфейсы, в частности не слушает интерфейс, который соединяет хост и докер.

Это тоже просто проверить используя простейшее приложение и выполнив команду для доступа к нему из докера:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Так что, используйте `127.0.0.1` (или 0.0.0.0 чтоб слушать вообще все интерфейсы) при запуске приложение на nodejs.